# Trying to avoid .Select or .Activate but fails with Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a small macro with some loops, works great, but now trying to clean up and avoid using .Select and .Activate, but when doing so, i run in to "Error 1004"

Got it working perfect using .Select for the sheet to look for data, and then .Select back to the sheet where it should paste.

Here some code:

```
Sub Sæt_ind_i_eksporten()

Dim dagensliste As Worksheet
Dim trailerliste As Worksheet
Dim trailernummer As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim targetcount As Integer

Set trailerliste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data ud (2)")
Set dagensliste = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

targetcount = trailerliste.Cells(30, 1).End(xlDown).Row

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For t = 30 To targetcount
trailernummer = trailerliste.Cells(t, 3).Value

    For i = 4 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 3) = trailernummer Then

            ' Here is where it fails - If I select the sheet manually, it moves on
            trailerliste.Range(Cells(t, 1), Cells(t, 13)).Copy

            ' And here it fails again (logic i know!) select manually again and it moves on.
            dagensliste.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     
        End If
    Next i
Next t

Application.GoTo reportsheet.Range(A1)

MsgBox ("Søgning gennemført")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If i replace `trailerliste.Range(Cells(t, 1), Cells(t, 13)).Copy` with `trailerliste.select` and `Range(Cells(t, 1), Cells(t, 13)).Copy` on separate lines, and the same for `dagensliste.Select` then the code works perfect.

I know it's a simple thing, but i tried reading all i could find on the forum with no luck.

I hope one can help me :)

Kind regards

Comment: Try: `dagensliste.Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: `Activesheet` is a rather 'dangerous' practice since what would happen if the macro starts from another worksheet? Rather specify the sheetname and use `With... End With` blocks.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you need to copy/paste values instead of referencing cells?

Comment: The data im copying is changing everyday, so a reference will cause the data in the destination to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range(Cells(x,y)) is tricky because you have to specify the Worksheet where the Cells are.

```
trailerliste.Range(Cells(t, 1), Cells(t, 13)).Copy
```

has to be

```
trailerliste.Range(trailerliste.Cells(t, 1), trailerliste.Cells(t, 13)).Copy
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
trailerliste.Range(Cells(t, 1), Cells(t, 13)).Copy
```

is equivalent to:

```
trailerliste.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(t, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(t, 13)).Copy
```

If `trailerListe` happens to be the active worksheet then this will work OK. If a different worksheet is active then this will cause an error.

Using `Range(Cells, Cells)` incorrectly is one of the most common sources of error in Excel VBA. It requires three different references to a worksheet and all three have to refer to the same worksheet.

This would work:

```
trailerliste.Range(trailerliste.Cells(t, 1), trailerliste.Cells(t, 13)).Copy
```

but it's usually easier to use a [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) block:

```
With trailerliste
    .Range(.Cells(t, 1), .Cells(t, 13)).Copy
End With
```

Any reference which starts with a `.` refers to the object in the `With` block - `trailerliste` in this case.

The similar `Range` call on `dagensliste` needs to be changed to a `With` block as well

Comment: I actually tried the With block, but that triggerede the same error on me?

Comment: Note that there are three `.` characters when using the With block. One in front of `Range` and one in front of each call to `Cells`. Double-check that all three are there or just copy and paste the code in the answer